# geoserver fails to start with jdbcconfig community module

Tags: geoserver, sql, oracle-dbms

I have installed the geoserver JDBC config community module, but now geoserver fails to start. I have set the properties to connect to an oracle database like this:

```
#Default GeoServer JDBC config driver and connection pool options. Edit as appropriate.
#Mon Aug 18 13:46:46 CEST 2014
enabled=true
initdb=true
initScript=${GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR}/jdbcconfig/scripts/initdb.oracle.sql
import=true
jdbcUrl=jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx.xxx.local:1521/dbname
driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
username=username
password=password
pool.minIdle=4
pool.maxActive=20
pool.poolPreparedStatements=true
pool.maxOpenPreparedStatements=100
pool.testOnBorrow=true
pool.validationQuery=SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;
```

However when I start geoerserver it returns the following stacktrace:

> 2014-08-28 17:40:19,377 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] - Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'geoServerLoader' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.5.1.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'JDBCGeoServerLoader' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-jdbcconfig-2.5-SNAPSHOT.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'JDBCCatalogFacade' while setting bean property 'catalogFacade'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'JDBCCatalogFacade' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-jdbcconfig-2.5-SNAPSHOT.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'JDBCConfigDB' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'JDBCConfigDB' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-jdbcconfig-2.5-SNAPSHOT.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jdbcConfigDataSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcConfigDataSource': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-00911: invalid character
>   )
>     etc lots more stack
>     etc
>     etc
>     etc
>     .
>     .
>     .
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00911: invalid character
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:743)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:207)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:790)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1037)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CStatement.java:830)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1132)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1272)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:208)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:208)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateConnection(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:658)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1558)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
>       ... 94 more

Bottomline is that it returns an invalid character error.
I have have looked at the provided initdb.oracle.sql, but cannot find anything wrong.
Even when I have only 1 line which I typed myself it fails on the ORA-0911 error. For instance the first line:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_OBJECT;
```

This also fails on the invalid character error. I also tried this without the semicolon.
Any suggestions?
I am using geoserver 2.5.1 and have downloaded the appropriated JDBCconfig files. I am trying to connect to an oracle 11 database. I am working on a windows 7 desktop.
I have only added what I think is the interesting part of the stacktrace, but i can add the rest if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what caused it.
I had to remove all semi-colons from all queries, both from the jdbcconfig.properties file as well as from the initdb.oracle.sql file.